# My animated object is distorted during export

Tags: export, .fbx, distort

I downloaded a model from the internet and found it.
animated (it was already gerigged). In Blender it looked like this:

[image: SpikeBrawlStarsRiggedInBlender]:

After I exported it, it looked very distorted:[image: SpikeBrawlStarsAfterExport]

I don't know much about Blender, but I've tried everything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: @four two
no unfortunately not, but thanks for your help